# Are there any permanent complications for defeating Town Guards?

Tags: last-dream

Are there any permanent complications for defeating Town Guards?

Allow me to explain why I ask this:

The game seems to warn the player about town guards when stealing from inhabited homes' chests (or in my case, I simply asked the inn owner if I could stay for free :) ), when I got attacked by town guards. I dispatched them, and now I wonder - was that a good idea? Will there be complications in the long run (like my characters being attacked more frequently by them just wandering in towns for having a possible bounty on their heads..)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no permanent complications from defeating town guards. In fact when you leave and return to the same town the town guards will be replaced with new ones. I'm not sure exactly when it resets but when I left town and went to grind gold in a nearby forest, the guards were back.

They receive no stat boosts each time you defeat them, but towns that you enter further into the game have tougher and tougher guards.

(Side note: The town guards are a part of the beastiary and if you want to have a complete catalog, feel free to harass the innkeepers.)

Answer found in a steam discussion (Link below)
http://steamcommunity.com/app/266230/discussions/0/540736319847426620/

Comment: And harass them I shall >:P there is a reason why I play the game on Grind > Legendary, love the challenge